# Do too many subquries create multiple sleeping processes in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, subquery, java

I am using java & MySQL to make an app. 
When I check the process list. I see a lot of sleeping processes. It also reaches to a points when no further connection is allowed.

I have read many answers around which tell the command to masskill the process or some suggests checking the code for bug.  I have checked that I'm closing the connections properly using the Apache Commons DbUtils.

```
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(rs);
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(statement);
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(con);
```

I am not able to figure out why these processes don't get killed after closing the connection.

My question is

1. Do too many subquries create multiple sleeping processes in MySQL? I don't see much relation though and didn't find anything on search.
2. Does passing connection object through methods create extra/multiple processes?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

One connection = one process (or thread).  Period.  Subqueries, `UNIONs`, and `PARTITIONing` do not create subprocesses.

What causes Sleeping processes:

- Connections that are busy with non-SQL work.  (Usually 'Time' is 0 or small.)
- Connections that don't go away.
- Connection pooling at the client.

Sleeping processes are relatively harmless.  No need to kill them.  All connections (sleeping or not) are capped at `max_connections`, after which, trying to get a new connection gets an error.

On the other hand, sometimes the client(s) have parameters that lead to an unreasonable number of connections.  Apache has what used to be called `MaxClients`, which (in my opinion) should not be set higher than 20.